# How to return columns before update using returning?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hey in PL/SQL consider this query :

```
update cards s set s.column1= null, s.column2= null
where s.column3= in_column3
returning s.column1,s.column2
into v_column1,v_column2;
```

Problem is this puts the new records in the variables, which are null but I'm intrested in the values before the update.

Is there any way I can achieve this using `RETURNING` clause?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522950/oracle-sql-can-i-return-the-before-state-of-a-column-value/40523568#40523568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, returning will give you the column values that result after the update. So better select the column values before you update.

```
select s.column1,
       s.column2
into v_column1,v_column2
from cards s
where s.column3= in_column3;
```

Comment: Ya this is the regular way, thought I might find a shortcut :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a **before update trigger** on this table which will store the previous values in a specific table in a specific condition. Or you can prevent the insertion if the new values being inserted are null.