# Oracle SQL - can I return the "before" state of a column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume the following row in myTable:

```
id     =  1
letter = 'a'
```

In Oracle, one can easily do the following:

```
update myTable set
  letter = 'b'
where id   = 1
returning letter 
into myVariable;
```

and myVariable will then hold the value 'b'.

What I am looking for is some way of returning the "before" value of letter

ie. replace the previous update with:

```
update myTable set
  letter = 'b'
where id   = 1
returning letter "before the update"
into myVariable;
```

**and myVariable should then hold the value 'a';**

I understand that T-SQL can achieve this via the OUTPUT clause.

Is there an Oracle equivalent way of achieving this so I don't have to first do a "select" just to get the before value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
update
  (
   select T.*, (select letter from DUAL) old_letter
     from myTable T
    where id=1
  )
   set letter = 'b'
returning old_letter into myVariable;
```

Tested on Oracle 11.2

Comment: This is intriguing.

Comment: Brillant solution!. It can be simplified a bit, just `select T.*, T.letter  AS old_letter .....`

Comment: @krokodilko I tested "simplified" `letter as old_letter` - not working. Oracle in this case return new value. Only subselect deceive Oracle

Comment: @Mike It doesn't deceive Oracle subselect just invokes scalar subquery caching.

Comment: @mike - thanks for your answer: A very interesting approach but not one I would personally choose to use for 2 main reasons: a. on the surface it doesn't appear any more efficient than doing a select followed by an update (which is my primary aim here); and b. from a maintenance perspective it is to me far less readable than simply doing a select followed by an update.

Comment: @Pancho - `it doesn't appear any more efficient than doing a select followed by an update` - **it IS more efficient** because requires only ONE operation instead of TWO. Just do a simple experiment and you will see - run both procedures (single update vs. select+update) 10.000  times in a loop and compare their execution times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can not do it with a simple SQL statement (and I'm wrong, seeing Mikes' answer :-) )

One way could be using another column and a trigger; for example, say you have a table with the column `a`, you may add another column `old_a` to store the old value of `a` and populate it with a trigger:

```
create table testUpdate(a number, old_a number);
create or replace trigger trgUpdate 
before update on testUpdate
for each row
begin
    if :new.a != :old.a then /* assuming not null values for simplicity */
        :new.old_a := :old.a;
    end if;
end; 
insert into testUpdate values (1, null);
```

When you run the update, the old value is stored in th `old_a` column and returned by the `returning` clause

```
SQL> declare
  2      vA number;
  3  begin
  4      update testUpdate
  5      set a = 9
  6      returning old_a
  7      into vA;
  8      --
  9      dbms_output.put_line(vA);
 10  end;
 11  /
1
```

However, given that this needs to add a column and a trigger to your table, I consider this solution more an exercise than something I would like to have in a production DB

Comment: thanks very much @Aleksej - as per my comment to Mike I would choose select followed by update over this approach. However, your answer I suppose highlights what I find strange: that Oracle triggers have access to the :old and :new values but from the answers I am seeing here Oracle doesn't expose the same functionality via SQL. There are so many use cases for it I couldn't even begin to list them all.

Answer (score 1):

If there is not much updates you can do update in loop and get old values:

```
declare
CURSOR c IS SELECT letter, id FROM myTable 
  FOR UPDATE OF letter;
begin
  open c;
  for x in c loop
     -- old value is in x.letter. You can assign it here
     update myTable set letter = 'b' where id = x.id;      
  end loop;
  commit;
  close c;
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks very much @Kacper - I think I would prefer to use select followed by update over this approach

Comment: @Pancho Yes I also think that select is better.

Answer (score 0):

Along with other super cool features like native boolean support, I'm very pleased to see that **Oracle 23c** introduces a tidy way of achieving my requirement above, so I thought I'd share it!

Here is the relevant excerpt from the [Oracle Database & Cloud Technology Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/coretec/post/oracle-database-23c-free-developer-sql) :

**RETURNING clause of UPDATE and MERGE statement**

> This clause has been implemented long time ago as a part of EXECUTE
> IMMEDIATE statement. However in Oracle Database 23c we can find it as
> a part of traditional, static DML statements - in this case it allows
> for obtaining old and new values of columns from a row processed by
> such statement:
>
> SQL> SELECT ename, sal FROM emp
> WHERE ename = 'KING';
>
> ENAME             SAL
>
> ---
>
> KING             5000
>
> SQL> VARIABLE old_salary NUMBER SQL> VARIABLE new_salary NUMBER
>
> SQL> UPDATE emp
> SET sal=sal+1000
> WHERE ename = 'KING'
> RETURNING OLD sal, NEW sal into :old_salary, :new_salary; 1 row updated.
>
> ### SQL> PRINT old_salary OLD_SALARY
>
> ```
>   5000
> ```
>
> ### SQL> PRINT new_salary NEW_SALARY
>
> ```
>   6000
> ```